# SleekXmpp custom stanza to parse Google's CCS xmpp response

Tags: android, python, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write a simple XMPP push notification 3rd party server in python and I'm using SleekXMPP.

When my app sends an upstream message, i receive a message like

```
<message id="3" type="error" to="123456789@gcm.googleapis.com/ABC">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
     { Json Arrays }
  </gcm>
  <error code="400" type="modify">
    <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    <text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">
      InvalidJson: JSON_PARSING_ERROR : Missing Required Field: message_id\n
    </text>
  </error>
</message>
```

But reading SleekXMPP's documents doesn't help much on understanding what should i use to get the content of this tag `<gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">`and change it to json so i can further use it.

What I understood was that I have to implement my custom stanza template, but with what i wrote, It's always returning empty :

```
class GCMMessage(ElementBase):
    name = 'gcm'
    namespace = 'google:mobile:data'
    plugin_attrib = 'gcm'
    interfaces = {'to', 'message_id',
                  'data', 'time_to_live',
                  'delay_if_idle',
                  'delivery_receipt_requested'
                  }
    sub_interfaces = interfaces
```

the result is:

```
GCMMessage(xml=msg.find('{google:mobile:data}gcm')).keys()
```

returns

```
['to', 'time_to_live', 'delay_if_idle', 'delivery_receipt_requested', 'data', 'message_id', u'lang']
```

while all values of those keys are "".

```
GCMMesage(xml=msg).get('to) = None
```

I even tried going for the child elements using :

```
GCMMessage(xml=msg.xml.getchildren()[0])
```

But then again, keys() returns my push notification keys but get returns None.

**How should I use define my custom stanzas and how should I use them ? How can I get the error stanza since it has no namespace ? **

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you just want to get JSON object from `gcm` element you does not need to subclass `Message`:

```py
json_data = msg.find('{google:mobile:data}gcm').text
```

will return you desired JSON, and you can work directly with it:

```py
import json 
jsonobject = json.loads(json_data)
```

2. In your `GCMMessage` you have defined interfaces but forgot to implement how to get values. You need to add at least `getXXX` for each desired field, like:

```py
# don't forget to read jsonobject in class initialization
def getData(self):  
    return jsonobject["data"]
```

and then it will work as expected:

```
GCMMessage(xml=msg.xml)["data"] # will return value from json data field
```